# Radio button drawable top not showing with setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(); and with setButtonDrawable(); showing in wrong position

Tags: android

I got Radio Button with button set as a drawable bottom in the layout. In java I set drawable top with `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.wrong,0,R.drawable.check);` method and drawable top is not showing.

So I tried different method with `setButtonDrawable();` which doesn't change the Radio Button `drawablebottom`, which is good and it sets the Drawable in place next to Button.

[image].

How to change its position to top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse your previous drawable to preserve the drawable bottom with:

```
Drawable drawableTop = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.wrong);
//Drawable drawableBottom = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.check);

Drawable[] drawables = button.getCompoundDrawables();
// left top right bottom
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawables[0], drawableTop, drawables[2], drawables[3]);
```

Or you can try the following:

```
Drawable drawableTop = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.wrong);
Drawable drawableBottom = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.check);

int topHeight = drawableTop.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
int topWidth = drawableTop.getIntrinsicWidth();   
drawableTop.setBounds(0, 0, topWidth, topHeight);

topHeight = drawableBottom.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
topWidth = drawableBottom.getIntrinsicWidth();   
drawableBottom.setBounds(0, 0, topWidth, topHeight);

button.setCompoundDrawables(null, drawableTop, null, drawableBottom);
```